# Changing KML tag structure

Tags: qgis, shapefile, google-maps, kml, google-earth

I am working on google-maps kml. I have several shapefiles and using QGIS i have converted it to kml files. When i export the kml (save as kml in Qgis). It contains tag like 
`<SimpleData name="Name">7</SimpleData>` but i want tag structure like 
`<Data name="name">
                        <value>7</value>
                    </Data>` I have export the shape as kml and update the kml change style add BalloonStyle for that i need to modify structure otherwise it will not display info in popup window.Here is the link for rules of tag structure to display popup in google map [as per kml extended data](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/extendeddata) 
 If we use `<SimpleData>` tag then popup will not display lables in google map
 [image: wrong popup]
When i change the structure of tags to `<Data><Value>`it will works gr8 ,Expected popup window is [image: expected popup]
 I just want to change the tag structure.

Is there an automated way to change the tag structure from kml file?

For example, like below `<simppledata>` to `<data><value>`

```
<SchemaData schemaUrl="#new_circle">
                <SimpleData name="Name">7</SimpleData>
                <SimpleData name="gid">1</SimpleData>
                <SimpleData name="active_sub">4596</SimpleData>
                <SimpleData name="net_additi">5181</SimpleData>
                <SimpleData name="gross_addi">3917</SimpleData>
                <SimpleData name="churn">4617</SimpleData>
            </SchemaData>`
```

to

```
<Data name="name">
                    <value>7</value>
                </Data>
                <Data name="active_sub">
                    <value>4596</value>
                </Data>
                <Data name="net_additi">
                    <value>5181</value>
                </Data>
                <Data name="gross_additi">
                    <value>3917</value>
                </Data>
                <Data name="churn">
                    <value>4617</value>
                </Data>
```

here is the sample link in which i have commented the simpledata tag and add manually data and value tag.[expected kml output](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/cbwf6ghyqu5lzdl/newCircle.kml) To do it manually will take maximum time because i have thousands of records in other layers.

Answer (score 2):

I have updated the kml by creating java class using jdom library.For that i need to do some manual task. Remove kml tag and then process file.
Here is the class i have created for this

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import org.jdom.Document;
import org.jdom.Element;
import org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder;
import org.jdom.output.XMLOutputter;
/**
 * @author amit
 */
public class XMLParser {
    private void getXMLDetails() {
        try {
            SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
            File file = new File("sample.xml");
            if (file.exists()) {
                Document document = (Document) builder.build(file);
                Element root = document.getRootElement();
                System.out.println(root.getChildren());
                Element firstTag = root.getChild("Folder");
                //firstTag.getAttribute("tag").setValue("file");
                List rootdata = firstTag.getChildren();
                System.out.println(rootdata);
                for(Iterator<Element> i = rootdata.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
                    Element rootitem =i.next();
                    if(rootitem.getName() =="Placemark"){
                    System.out.println(rootitem.getChildren("ExtendedData"));
                    List listdata = rootitem.getChild("ExtendedData").getChild("SchemaData").getChildren();
                    for(Iterator<Element> j = listdata.iterator(); j.hasNext(); ) {
                        Element item =j.next();
                        System.out.println(item);
                        String gidval = item.getText();
                        Element gid = new Element("value").setText(gidval);
                        item.setText("");
                        item.addContent(gid);
                        System.out.println("test");
                    }
                    }
                }
                String des = new XMLOutputter().outputString(document);
                des = des.replaceAll("SimpleData", "Data");
                des = des.replaceAll("</SchemaData>", "");
                des = des.replaceAll("<SchemaData schemaUrl=\"#new_area\">", "");
                System.out.println("String: " + des.replaceAll("SimpleData", "Data"));
                FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
                fileWriter.write(des);
                fileWriter.close();
            } else {
                System.out.println("File does not exist");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String argS[]) {
        try {
            new XMLParser().getXMLDetails();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the link for jar[JDOM library](http://www.jdom.org/dist/binary/jdom-2.0.5.zip)